# View not displayed when created from SearchView onQueryTextSubmit

Tags: android, android-view, searchview

I want to search for locations in a searchview and display the location on a map with a marker. When the marker is clicked, I want to show a infowindow with the location name, etc. I use OSMDROID and the OSMBONUSPACK.

**The Problem:**
The marker is shown as intented and its onClickListener does fire, but the infowindow is not shown if I call my `searchLocationOnMap` from `onQueryTextSubmit`. How to fix that?

**Does not work**(no info window shown if marker is clicked)**:**

```
 searchViewMap?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            val location = searchViewMap?.query.toString()
            if (location != null && location != "") {
                try {
                    searchLocationOnMap("Moosach Bhf")
                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    Timber.d("Error while searching for location on map")
                }
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

    })
```

For some reason it is shown if I call `searchLocationOnMap` from `onViewCreated` or from a regular `button.setOnClickListener{}`.

**Does work**(infowindow shown if marker is clicked)**:**

```
btn.setOnClickListener { searchLocationOnMap("Moosach Bhf") }
```

This is searchLocationOnMap():

```
private fun searchLocationOnMap(keyword: String) = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    removeOldLocationsFromMap()

    val locationAddress = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { obtainAddressFromKeyword(keyword) }

    if (locationAddress == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No address found for keyword $keyword", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
            val marker = createMarkerFromAddress(locationAddress)

            mPOIOverlayFolder.add(marker)
            map.controller.animateTo(marker.position)
            map.invalidate()

    }
```

This is obtainAdressFromKeyword:

```
 private fun obtainAddressFromKeyword(keyword: String): Address? {
    val result = GeocoderNominatim("TestUserAgent").getFromLocationName(keyword, 1).firstOrNull()
    Timber.d("result: $result")
    return result
}
```

This is createMarkerFromAddress:

```
private fun createMarkerFromAddress(address: Address): Marker {
    val poiMarker = Marker(map)
    poiMarker.title = address.getAddressLine(0)
    poiMarker.snippet = "Lat : ${address.latitude},\n Long ${address.longitude}"
    poiMarker.position = GeoPoint(address.latitude, address.longitude)
    poiMarker.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.poi_black)
    poiMarker.infoWindow = MarkerInfoWindow(R.layout.marker_info_bubble, map)
    poiMarker.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker, map -> onMarkerClick(marker) }


    return poiMarker
}
```

This is onMarkerClick:

```
private fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker) : Boolean {
    marker.showInfoWindow()
    marker.infoWindow.view.bringToFront()
    Timber.d("Clicked Marker ${marker.title}, infowindowshown: ${marker.isInfoWindowShown}")

    return true
```

Timber result (in both cases):

> Clicked Marker Memminger Platz, infowindowshown: true

Comment: Did u added this line in onMapReady ? googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MyClass.this);

Comment: I use OSMDroid and the OSMBonuspack, not google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map.parent view has to be invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with something like this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Log.i("MyApp", searchView.getQuery().toString());
        consultarListaParadas(searchView.getQuery().toString());
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                adaptadorListaParadasBus.setListaParadas(listaParadas);
                adaptadorListaParadasBus.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        if(newText.equals("")){
            this.onQueryTextSubmit("");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```